# What is the best place to put a JavaScript listening function in Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngoninit

**TL;DR:**

I am rendering a [BioDigital HumanAPI](https://www.biodigital.com/) anatomical model in my Angular 5 app within an `iFrame`. I instantiate API object using:

```
this.human = new HumanAPI(iFrameSrc);
```

There's an API function `human.on(...)` that can be used to register click events from within `iFrame` (like picking objects from the model, etc.). I need this function to be able to listen to the events at all times. I do the object instantiation and put this function within `ngOnInit()` and it works, but when I change the source of `iFrame` to render a different model, this function stops working. Where should I put this listening function so that its logic is available at all times?

**Longer version:**

I am developing an Angular app using BioDigital HumanAPI. The basic idea here is that HumanAPI provides several anatomical models which can be rendered in a web-app using an `iFrame` (an example [here](https://codepen.io/biodigital/pen/4f2da0e54e201754a0c0d9ef11d5a1cb)). The `src` of this `iFrame` is a link, something like:

```
https://human.biodigital.com/widget?m=congestive_heart_failure
```

Since I want the user of my Angular app to be able to view several of such models, I have a list of these URLs, and based on user's selection, I update the `src` of `iFrame`, using a function `updateFrameSrc` which has following code:

```
iframeSrc: SafeUrl;
this.iframeSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(newUrl);
```

Finally (the question is coming, please stay with me), in order to manipulate and register different click events and user interactions with the model within the `iFrame` itself, we make a HumanAPI object like this:

```
this.human = new HumanAPI(iFrameID);
```

This lets us use API event listener functions like `human.on('scene.picked')` to register and save click events (like shown in the example I referenced above). All of this is working fine.

The problem is that since I initialize the `human` object in the `ngOnInit()` function and also put the `human.on('scene.picked')` function there, I cannot register the click events after the `iFrame` source is changed. As I understand it, `ngOnInit()` is only called once when the component is first initialized, so *may be* the listening logic of `human.on` is not available after updating the `iFrame` source? I have tried placing the logic in different life-cycle hooks but its doesn't work.

**My current work-around** is to re-call the `ngOnInit()` function after updating the `iFrame` source, and it works that way, but I believe this is against the standard life-cycle management practices.

My questions are:

- It is acceptable to re-call the `ngOnInit()` function from within the component logic?
- If not, where should I place a JavaScript API function that listens to click events from an `iFrame` at all times, even after the source of that `iFrame` has been changed?

Comment: why can't you just move the two lines you need from ngOnInit() into a separate function and call that function in both ngOnInit and in your updateFrameSrc function?

Comment: @AbrahamAl-Dabbagh Okay, this was the answer after all. I had tried it this way but I was forgetting to initialize the `human` object again after updating `iFrame` source. Kindly add this as an answer so that I may accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in an earlier comment, you can just move the code in `ngOnInit()` to a separate function and call that function from both `ngOnInit()` as well as your update function.

Don't forget to re-initialize the `human` object of `HumanAPI` in that function as well, when updating the `iFrame` source.

Re-calling `ngOnInit()` should be avoided as it circumvents the acceptable functionality of lifecycle hooks, as mentioned by [@iHazCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8657553/ihazcode).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for near real time you will want this to occur in the NgOnChanges life-cycle hook. Be advised this is expensive.

If slightly less "near real time" is acceptable, I would advise wiring up a rapid delay subject `Observable.Interval(500)` (also, but slightly less expensive) at the time of Component initialization NgOnInit.

Please DO NOT circumvent the hooks by re-calling ngOnInit.

If you have additional questions let me know.

Comment: I tried doing it using `ngOnChanges()` but as you said, it is _very_ expensive for my app. The thing is, putting listener logic in `ngOnInit()` works fine as long as I don't change the `iFrame` source and without using delays or something that, kind of, _force listens_ to events (like on every mouseDown event). Recalling `ngOnInit()` works too, so I was thinking that may be some less expensive workaround exists as well.

Comment: I just did something similar by bootstrapping a periodic task (Observable.Interval) inside of the NgOnInit. It will work, and for most use cases the DOM will render fast enough that the operator/user will not perceive any delay over putting it in the ngOnChanges. Please do not recall ngOnInit. It causes problems that may not be immediately apparent.